# Nth term of this sequence? Does it converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find the $n^{th}$ term of this sequence?$$u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{1}{u_n}$$

I have only studied geometric and arithmetic sequences in high school and was curious to see what the $n^{th}$ term of a series like this would look like.

I can see that $u_{n+1} - u_n$ is decreasing as $n$ increases. Which also has me wondering whether the series converges.

Comment: @DonThousand Are you sure it "approaches the harmonic series", if so to what extent? Note that the term $\approx n$ appears approximately $n$ times, instead of just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice the $u_{n+1}$ is the $x$-intercept of the tangent line to the curve $$f(x) =e^{-x^2/2}$$ at the point $(u_n, f(u_n))$

thus if you start at a positive $u_1$ the sequence diverges to $+\infty $ and if you start with a negative $u_1$ it diverges to  $-\infty $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if there was a limit, what would happen when you take the limit of both sides of the equation $u_{n+1} = u_n + 1/u_n$?